# pywal wont run on startx

Tags: x11, startx, xinit

I'm having some trouble starting pywal through .xinitrc
Currently my .xinitrc is:

```
exec dwm
wal -i "/home/joe/pictures/wallpapers" &
```

Anyone know what I could have messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `exec dwm`, the shell process that is executing the `.xinitrc` script will be replaced with `dwm`, and so any commands in `.xinitrc` after that will be totally ignored.

Will it work if you just swap the order of those two lines?

```
wal -i "/home/joe/pictures/wallpapers" &
exec dwm
```

Or does this have some undesirable side effects, like flickering as the window manager starts up? If so, you'll need to find some way to have `dwm` run the `wal ...` command, as the `.xinitrc` script interpreter process simply won't exist any more after `exec dwm` is executed.